# SQL Server - Image Expression

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS.

I have created a car park map with set locations, each car park will have a different vehicle parked in said location. I want to create an expression to add to the image for each park to identify what is parked there and based on the column data display a different image.

For example:

```
=CASE
WHEN ParkingSpot = x AND NumberPlate = Y THEN "IMAGE OF THAT CAR.JPG"
```

I've tried a few different variations of the above but I've had no luck. If there is a better way of doing this be querying for the car's current location and creating a variable etc please let me know.

I've tried a switch but I need more information.

```
=CASE
WHEN ParkingSpot = x AND NumberPlate = Y THEN "IMAGE OF THAT CAR.JPG"
```

So in short what I'm trying to achieve is for each parking bay to show a picture of which car is there depending on the location/plate values.

```
If ParkingSpot = 4A AND NumberPlate = XXX-XXX THEN "Display Car Image"
```

Comment: please post your sample code, input of your data and expected output. comparison between your current output and expected output is preferable to understand the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
=Switch(Fields!ParkingSpot.Value="4A" AND Fields!NumberPlate="ABC-DEF", "image.jpg" )
```